# Dynamic resizing of google reCaptcha

Tags: html, css, recaptcha

I am using Google reCaptcha in my form. And as soon as I change the size of the window to a smartphone size the Captcha messes with my width.

I looked at the answer for resizing the Captcha when loading it, but that just does not cut it. I already started designing a responsive layout. I can't stop here.

Answer (score 0):

Google Recaptcha 2.0 does not allow theme customization. But you can use `css scale` hack as Rahamathullah's answer shows. It is not nice, but it solves the problem.

You can also try using the data-size attribute:
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#render_param

Answer (score 0):

try this code on  you css

```
.g-recaptcha {
transform: scale(0.8);
-webkit-transform:scale(0.8);
transform-origin:0 0;
-webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
max-width: 240px;
}
```